# ListView Selected position with setTextFilterEnabled

Tags: android, android-listview

I have the following code that starts a listview with 100 options. Also it activates the software keyboard, for easy-searching of the options. If i choose an option, the position of the selected option stores in the string array items[]. The problem is that when i  search an option by keyword, select it and then go back, it points at the current position not at the current value.

How to prevent this?

```
public class MyListActivity extends ListActivity {
    String[] items;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.list);
        ListView lView = getListView();
        lView.setChoiceMode(2); 
        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                   WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        lView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items1);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, items));
     }
       public void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View v, int position, long id) {
           lv.setItemChecked(position, lv.isItemChecked(position));
           String selectedValue = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
           Toast.makeText(this, selectedValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should create your own custom Adapter , and then in that adapter just simply override the `getItem(int position)` function to return the value that you need. If u haven't done it before then check out for instance [this tutorial](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)

Comment: My code is almost same with this one [link]http://www.yogeshblogspot.com/how-to-get-selected-items-from-multi-select-list-view/ The problem appears when i search for an option, then select it(one or more), and go back twice with the "back" button. The checked boxes doesn't follow the values, but the positions. Could anybody please let me know about the changes i have to do in my code for the result i want?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, having a filterable adapter doesn't play well with any choice mode (single or multiple). The only solution to this is to manually maintain the state of the selected items (a set or a list of strings in your case), and then simply loop through it every time you change the filter, in order to select the items you need. This has already been described in great detail here: [Multiple Choice Searchable ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122974/multiple-choice-searchable-listview)

You obviously can't use the setTextFilterEnabled() method for this, you simply need to add an EditText in your layout and then set a TextWatcher on that in order to get all the necessary callbacks.