# getting all selected from listview

Tags: android, android-listview, adapter

I have a listview with searchview and multiple selection option.For that i'm trying the following code that is as follows..

Mainactivity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Context context = null;

    ContactsAdapter objAdapter;

    ListView lv = null;

    EditText edtSearch = null;
    LinearLayout llContainer = null;
    Button btnOK = null;

    RelativeLayout rlPBContainer = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        context = this;

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rlPBContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.pbcontainer);

        edtSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_search);
        llContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.data_container);
        btnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok_button);

        btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                getSelectedContacts();
            }
        });

        edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                String text = edtSearch.getText().toString()
                        .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                objAdapter.filter(text);
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1,
                                          int arg2, int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        addContactsInList();

    }

    private void getSelectedContacts() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        for (ContactObject bean : ContactsListClass.phoneList) {

            if (bean.isSelected()) {
                sb.append(bean.getName());
                sb.append(",");
            }
        }

        String s = sb.toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Select atleast one Contact",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Selected Contacts : " + s,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }

    private void addContactsInList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                showPB();

                try {

                    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null, null, null, null);

                    try {
                        ContactsListClass.phoneList.clear();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneName = phones
                                .getString(phones
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        String phoneNumber = phones
                                .getString(phones
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        String phoneImage = phones
                                .getString(phones
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));


                        ContactObject cp = new ContactObject();


                        cp.setName(phoneName);
                        cp.setNumber(phoneNumber);
                        cp.setImage(phoneImage);

                        ContactsListClass.phoneList.add(cp);

                    }
                    phones.close();

                    lv = new ListView(context);

                    lv.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            llContainer.addView(lv);
                        }
                    });

                    Collections.sort(ContactsListClass.phoneList,
                            new Comparator<ContactObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public int compare(ContactObject lhs,
                                                   ContactObject rhs) {
                                    return lhs.getName().compareTo(
                                            rhs.getName());
                                }
                            });

                    objAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                            ContactsListClass.phoneList);
                    lv.setAdapter(objAdapter);
                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                                View view, int position, long id) {

                            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) view
                                    .findViewById(R.id.contactcheck);
                            ContactObject bean = ContactsListClass.phoneList
                                    .get(position);
                            if (bean.isSelected()) {
                                bean.setSelected(false);
                                chk.setChecked(false);
                            } else {
                                bean.setSelected(true);
                                chk.setChecked(true);
                            }

                        }
                    });

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

                hidePB();

            }
        };
        thread.start();

    }

    void showPB() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                rlPBContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                edtSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnOK.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    void hidePB() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                rlPBContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                edtSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnOK.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Adapter class:-

```
public class ContactsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<ContactObject> mainDataList = null;
    private ArrayList<ContactObject> arraylist;

    public ContactsAdapter(Context context, List<ContactObject> mainDataList) {

        mContext = context;
        this.mainDataList = mainDataList;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        this.arraylist = new ArrayList<ContactObject>();
        this.arraylist.addAll(mainDataList);


    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView name;
        protected TextView number;
        protected CheckBox check;
        protected ImageView image;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mainDataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ContactObject getItem(int position) {
        return mainDataList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

            holder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactname);
            holder.number = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactno);

            holder.check = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.contactcheck);

            holder.image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactimage);

            view.setTag(holder);
            view.setTag(R.id.contactname, holder.name);
            view.setTag(R.id.contactno, holder.number);
            view.setTag(R.id.contactcheck, holder.check);

            holder.check
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton vw,
                                                     boolean isChecked) {

                            int getPosition = (Integer) vw.getTag();
                            mainDataList.get(getPosition).setSelected(
                                    vw.isChecked());

                        }
                    });

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        holder.check.setTag(position);

        holder.name.setText(mainDataList.get(position).getName());
        holder.number.setText(mainDataList.get(position).getNumber());

        if (getByteContactPhoto(mainDataList.get(position).getImage()) == null) {
            holder.image.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha);
        } else {
            holder.image.setImageBitmap(getByteContactPhoto(mainDataList.get(position).getImage()));
        }


        holder.check.setChecked(mainDataList.get(position).isSelected());

        return view;
    }

    public void filter(String charText) {
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
        mainDataList.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            mainDataList.addAll(arraylist);
        } else {
            for (ContactObject wp : arraylist) {
                if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                        .contains(charText)) {
                    mainDataList.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public Bitmap getByteContactPhoto(String contactId) {
        Uri contactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, Long.parseLong(contactId));
        Uri photoUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(contactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
        Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(photoUri,
                new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.DATA15}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                byte[] data = cursor.getBlob(0);
                if (data != null) {
                    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(data));
                }
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

my problem is 
step-1 : i have selected a contact from the listview.
step-2 : now i have searched for xxx contact and i selected it.
step-3 : now when i press on ok button it is retrieving only xxx contact.
step-4 : It needs to retrieve all the selected contacts from the view

How can i do that help me in solving this.

Comment: where is your getSelectedItems ?

Comment: it is hard to understand you ... but instead `mainDataList`  use `arraylist` for getting all, not only filtered selected items ...

Comment: @Blackbelt i have provided in the above code getSlectedContacts().

Comment: @Selvin in Mainactivity i need to retrieve you are saying it in the adatper.

Comment: is `private void getSelectedContacts()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122974/multiple-choice-searchable-listview)

I have taken the one array and added all the selected items before text changing this solved my problem.

MainActivity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Context context = null;

    ContactsAdapter objAdapter;

    ListView lv = null;

    EditText edtSearch = null;
    LinearLayout llContainer = null;
    Button btnOK = null;

    RelativeLayout rlPBContainer = null;

    ArrayList<String> selected = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        context = this;

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        rlPBContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.pbcontainer);

        edtSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_search);
        llContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.data_container);
        btnOK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok_button);

        btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                getSelectedContacts();
            }
        });

        edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                String text = edtSearch.getText().toString()
                        .toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                objAdapter.filter(text);


            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                          int count, int after) {

                for (ContactObject bean : ContactsListClass.phoneList) {

                    if (bean.isSelected()) {
                        selected.add(bean.getName());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        addContactsInList();

    }

    private void getSelectedContacts() {

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        for (ContactObject bean : ContactsListClass.phoneList) {

            if (bean.isSelected()) {
                selected.add(bean.getName());
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < selected.size(); i++) {
            sb.append(selected.get(i));
            sb.append(",");
        }


        String s = sb.toString().trim();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Select atleast one Contact",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {

            s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Selected Contacts : " + s,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }

    private void addContactsInList() {

        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                showPB();

                try {

                    Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null, null, null, null);

                    try {
                        ContactsListClass.phoneList.clear();
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }

                    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneName = phones
                                .getString(phones
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                        String phoneNumber = phones
                                .getString(phones
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        String phoneImage = phones
                                .getString(phones
                                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID));


                        ContactObject cp = new ContactObject();


                        cp.setName(phoneName);
                        cp.setNumber(phoneNumber);
                        cp.setImage(phoneImage);

                        ContactsListClass.phoneList.add(cp);

                    }
                    phones.close();

                    lv = new ListView(context);

                    lv.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            llContainer.addView(lv);
                        }
                    });

                    Collections.sort(ContactsListClass.phoneList,
                            new Comparator<ContactObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public int compare(ContactObject lhs,
                                                   ContactObject rhs) {
                                    return lhs.getName().compareTo(
                                            rhs.getName());
                                }
                            });

                    objAdapter = new ContactsAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                            ContactsListClass.phoneList);
                    lv.setAdapter(objAdapter);
                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                                View view, int position, long id) {

                            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox) view
                                    .findViewById(R.id.contactcheck);
                            ContactObject bean = ContactsListClass.phoneList
                                    .get(position);
                            if (bean.isSelected()) {
                                bean.setSelected(false);
                                chk.setChecked(false);
                            } else {
                                bean.setSelected(true);
                                chk.setChecked(true);
                            }

                        }
                    });

                } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

                hidePB();

            }
        };
        thread.start();

    }

    void showPB() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                rlPBContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                edtSearch.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnOK.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }

    void hidePB() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                rlPBContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                edtSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnOK.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make a list of objects and everytime user select an item in list view you add object contained in this view, and go further. If user wants to delete an object just search for it in your list and delete it.