# select mutiple contact list by searchview and send to another activity

Tags: android, search, multiple-choice

OK I have a multiple choice ListView that works fine. I check the boxes for the contacts (held in a String[]) and can return the values fine. Because some people have a bunch of contacts I wanted to create a search bar kind of like the stock one for the Android phone book. I created an EditText and aligned it above my list. I found the filtering code here on StackOverflow and it works wonderfully.

My Problem:

When you filter someones name out, and you select the name, when you either backspace from the EditText or continue typing, the correct position of the name you selected is not saved. For example, if I start typing "Adam" and get to "Ada" and select it, if I backspace to type in "Carol", whatever position "Ada" was at is selected. It gathers the place that "Adam" was at from the click (Let's say 2) and when the list is restored checks that position (2) even though Adam is not there anymore. I need a way to gather the name.. then when the list is restored or searched again, the NAME Adam is checked and not the POSITION Adam was previously at. I have absolutely no ideas other than creating tons of Arrays and could really use some help.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String[] items={"lorem1", "ipsum1", "dolor1",
            "sit1", "amet1","lorem2", "ipsum2", "dolor2",
            "sit2", "amet2","lorem3", "ipsum3", "dolor3",
            "sit3", "amet3","lorem4", "ipsum4", "dolor4",
            "sit4", "amet4","lorem5", "ipsum5", "dolor5",
            "sit5", "amet5","lorem6", "ipsum6", "dolor6",
            "sit6", "amet6","pigeon","victory"};
    ListView list;
    Button save;
    EditText inputSearch;
    SearchView searchview;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    int textlength=0;
  //  private String my_sel_items;
   ArrayList<String> selectedItems1 = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

adapter = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, items));

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    list.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
    list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
    list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);

            textlength = inputSearch.getText().length();
            selectedItems1.clear();
            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                if (textlength <= items[i].length()) {
                    if (inputSearch.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(
                            (String)
                                    items[i].subSequence(0,
                                            textlength))) {
                        selectedItems1.add(items[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>
                    (MainActivity.this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, selectedItems1));
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SparseBooleanArray checked = list.getCheckedItemPositions();
            ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {

                int position = checked.keyAt(i);

                if (checked.valueAt(i))
                    selectedItems.add(adapter.getItem(position));

            }

            String[] outputStrArr = new String[selectedItems.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < selectedItems.size(); i++) {
                outputStrArr[i] = selectedItems.get(i);
            }
            if (selectedItems.size() < 1) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Select atleast one ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);

                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putStringArray("selectedItems", outputStrArr);

                intent.putExtras(b);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

        }


    });
}
```

}

Comment: I have shared solution in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122974/multiple-choice-searchable-listview/38027799#38027799).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you can use unique ID's.
In every list item you can have an invisible TextView that will store the ID.
On click assign to some variable the ID and you can use it later.
Hope that helps.
Lets say your list items XML are as so:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal">
<!-- Contact name -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contactName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<!-- Contact Unique ID -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/contactID"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

In your activity class add the following variables:

```
static int uid;
int selectedId;
```

Then before initializing the list add:

```
uid = 0;
```

In the adapter or whatever way you add views to list do:

```
TextView id = (TextView)yourListItem.findViewById(R.id.contactID);
id.setText(String.valueOf(uid));
uid++;
```

And finally in the onClickListener of the list item add:

```
TextView id = (TextView)yourListItem.findViewById(R.id.contactID);
selectedId = Integer.parseInt(id.getText().toString());
```

That way you can fetch the selected list item later - by comparing the selected id.

Comment: I need to see your implementation to give you relevant samples.

Comment: Edited my answer to include an example

Comment: thanks for your response i edited my code can u check it once